# Property 'accelerometerEnabled' not found on object of type 'GameplayLayer *'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, properties, cocos2d-iphone

Based on the endless runner starter template found on https://www.makegameswith.us/tutorials/templates-get-started/the-templates/.  Supposedly it is only compatible with cocos 2d v2.x.  I'm using v3.x  But I'm not sure if things have changed....I'm only getting one error.

Here's where the error is in my GameplayLayer.m file:

```
 #pragma mark - Scene Lifecycle

 - (void)onEnterTransitionDidFinish
 {
// setup a gesture listener for jumping and stabbing gestures
[KKInput sharedInput].gestureSwipeEnabled = TRUE;
// register for accelerometer input, to controll the knight
self.accelerometerEnabled = YES; //error here

if (self.showMainMenu)
{
    // add main menu
    MainMenuLayer *mainMenuLayer = [[MainMenuLayer alloc] init];
    [self addChild:mainMenuLayer z:MAX_INT];
} else
{
    // start game directly
    [self showHUD:TRUE];
    [self startGame];
 }
 }

 - (void)onExit
 {
// very important! deactivate the gestureInput, otherwise touches on scrollviews and tableviews will be cancelled!
[KKInput sharedInput].gestureSwipeEnabled = FALSE;
self.accelerometerEnabled = FALSE; //error here
 }
```

Any ideas?

Using cocos 2d v3.x and xcode 5.2

**UPDATE:**

An excerpt of my GameLayer.h file with CoreMotion implemented:

```
 #import "CCScene.h"
 #import "StoreTableViewCell.h"
 #import "PauseScreen.h"
 #import "InGameStore.h"
 #import "ScoreboardEntryNode.h"
 #import "HealthDisplayNode.h"
 #import "PopUp.h"
 #import "Knight.h"

 #import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>

 @interface Scene : CCScene
 {
 CMMotionManager* motionManager;

 }
 @end

 @interface GameplayLayer : CCLayer <StoreDisplayNeedsUpdate, PauseScreenDelegate>
 {
HealthDisplayNode *healthDisplayNode;
ScoreboardEntryNode *coinsDisplayNode;
ScoreboardEntryNode *pointsDisplayNode;
ScoreboardEntryNode *inAppCurrencyDisplayNode;
// groups health, coins and points display
CCNode *hudNode;

/* Skip Ahead Button */
CCMenu *skipAheadMenu;
CCMenuItemSprite *skipAheadMenuItem;

/* Pause Button */
CCMenu *pauseButtonMenu;
CCMenuItemSprite *pauseButtonMenuItem;

/* "GO ON?" popup */
PopUp *goOnPopUp;

/* "Buy more coins"-Popup */
InGameStore *inGameStore;

Game *game;
Knight *knight;

/* used to trigger events, that need to run every X update cycles*/
int updateCount;

/* stores the exact distance the knight has ran */
float gainedDistance;
 }
```

In GameplayLayer.m:

```
 #import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>

 @implementation GameplayLayer

 + (id)scene
 {
CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
GameplayLayer* layer = [GameplayLayer node];

// By default we want to show the main menu
layer.showMainMenu = TRUE;

[scene addChild:layer];
return scene;
 }

 + (id)noMenuScene
 {
CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
GameplayLayer* layer = [GameplayLayer node];

// By default we want to show the main menu
layer.showMainMenu = FALSE;

[scene addChild:layer];
return scene;
 }

 // important: only create one instance of a motion manager
 CMMotionManager *_motionManager;
 CCLabelTTF *_label;

 - (id)init
 {
self = [super init];

if (self)
{
    // get screen center
    CGPoint screenCenter = [CCDirector sharedDirector].screenCenter;

    // preload particle effects
    // To preload the textures, play each effect once off-screen
    CCParticleSystem* system = [CCParticleSystemQuad particleWithFile:@"fx-explosion.plist"];
    system.positionType = kCCPositionTypeFree;
    system.autoRemoveOnFinish = YES;
    system.position = ccp(MAX_INT, MAX_INT);
    // adding it as child lets the particle effect play
    [self addChild:system];

    // add the scrolling background
    ParallaxBackground *background = [ParallaxBackground node];
    [self addChild:background z:-2];

    hudNode = [CCNode node];
    [self addChild:hudNode];

    // add the knight
    knight = [[Knight alloc] initWithKnightPicture];
    [self addChild:knight];
    knight.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);

    // add the health display
    healthDisplayNode = [[HealthDisplayNode alloc] initWithHealthImage:@"heart_filled.png" lostHealthImage:@"heart_empty.png" maxHealth:5];
    [hudNode addChild:healthDisplayNode z:MAX_INT-1];
    healthDisplayNode.position = ccp(screenCenter.x, self.contentSize.height - 18);

    // add scoreboard entry for coins
    coinsDisplayNode = [[ScoreboardEntryNode alloc] initWithScoreImage:@"coin.png" fontFile:@"avenir.fnt"];
    coinsDisplayNode.scoreStringFormat = @"%d";
    coinsDisplayNode.position = ccp(20, self.contentSize.height - 26);
    [hudNode addChild:coinsDisplayNode z:MAX_INT-1];

    // add scoreboard entry for in-app currency
    inAppCurrencyDisplayNode = [[ScoreboardEntryNode alloc] initWithScoreImage:@"coin.png" fontFile:@"avenir.fnt"];
    inAppCurrencyDisplayNode.scoreStringFormat = @"%d";
    inAppCurrencyDisplayNode.position = ccp(self.contentSize.width - 120, self.contentSize.height - 26);
    inAppCurrencyDisplayNode.score = [Store availableAmountInAppCurrency];
    [hudNode addChild:inAppCurrencyDisplayNode z:MAX_INT-1];

    // add scoreboard entry for points
    pointsDisplayNode = [[ScoreboardEntryNode alloc] initWithScoreImage:nil fontFile:@"avenir24.fnt"];
    pointsDisplayNode.position = ccp(10, self.contentSize.height - 50);
    pointsDisplayNode.scoreStringFormat = @"%d m";
    [hudNode addChild:pointsDisplayNode z:MAX_INT-1];

    // set up the skip ahead menu
    CCSprite *skipAhead = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"skipahead.png"];
    CCSprite *skipAheadSelected = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"skipahead-pressed.png"];
    skipAheadMenuItem = [CCMenuItemSprite itemWithNormalSprite:skipAhead selectedSprite:skipAheadSelected target:self selector:@selector(skipAheadButtonPressed)];
    skipAheadMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:skipAheadMenuItem, nil];
    skipAheadMenu.position = ccp(self.contentSize.width - skipAheadMenuItem.contentSize.width -20, self.contentSize.height - 80);
    // initially skipAheadMenu is hidden
    skipAheadMenu.visible = FALSE;
    [hudNode addChild:skipAheadMenu];

    // set up pause button
    CCSprite *pauseButton = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"pause.png"];
    CCSprite *pauseButtonPressed = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"pause-pressed.png"];
    pauseButtonMenuItem = [CCMenuItemSprite itemWithNormalSprite:pauseButton selectedSprite:pauseButtonPressed target:self selector:@selector(pauseButtonPressed)];
    pauseButtonMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:pauseButtonMenuItem, nil];
    pauseButtonMenu.position = ccp(self.contentSize.width - pauseButtonMenuItem.contentSize.width - 4, self.contentSize.height - 58);
    [hudNode addChild:pauseButtonMenu];

    // add the enemy cache containing all spawned enemies
    [self addChild:[EnemyCache node]];

    // add decorative node
    //[self addChild:[DecorativeObjectsNode node]];

    // setup a new gaming session
    [self resetGame];

    [self scheduleUpdate];

    /**
     A Notification can be used to broadcast an information to all objects of a game, that are interested in it.
     Here we sign up for the 'GamePaused' and 'GameResumed' information, that is broadcasted by the GameMechanics class. Whenever the game pauses or resumes, we get informed and can react accordingly.
     **/
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(gamePaused) name:@"GamePaused" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(gameResumed) name:@"GameResumed" object:nil];

    _label= [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"X" fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:48];
    [self addChild:_label];
    _motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
}

return self;
 }
```

I have no idea how to convert the following into CMMotionManager:

```
 #pragma mark - Reset Game

 - (void)startGame
 {
[[GameMechanics sharedGameMechanics] setGameState:GameStateRunning];
[self enableGamePlayButtons];
[self presentSkipAheadButtonWithDuration:5.f];

/*
 inform all missions, that they have started
 */
for (Mission *m in game.missions)
{
    [m missionStart:game];
}
 }

 - (void)resetGame
 {
[[GameMechanics sharedGameMechanics] resetGame];

game = [[Game alloc] init];
[[GameMechanics sharedGameMechanics] setGame:game];
[[GameMechanics sharedGameMechanics] setKnight:knight];
// add a reference to this gamePlay scene to the gameMechanics, which allows accessing the scene from other classes
[[GameMechanics sharedGameMechanics] setGameScene:self];

// set the default background scroll speed
[[GameMechanics sharedGameMechanics] setBackGroundScrollSpeedX:SCROLL_SPEED_DEFAULT];

/* setup initial values */

// setup knight
knight.position = ccp(50,20);
knight.zOrder = 10;
knight.hitPoints = KNIGHT_HIT_POINTS;

// setup HUD
healthDisplayNode.health = knight.hitPoints;
coinsDisplayNode.score = game.score;
pointsDisplayNode.score = game.meters;

// set spwan rate for monsters
[[GameMechanics sharedGameMechanics] setSpawnRate:25 forMonsterType:[BasicMonster class]];
[[GameMechanics sharedGameMechanics] setSpawnRate:50 forMonsterType:[SlowMonster class]];
[[GameMechanics sharedGameMechanics] setSpawnRate:50 forMonsterType:[MyCustomMonster class]];

// set gravity (used for jumps)
[[GameMechanics sharedGameMechanics] setWorldGravity:ccp(0.f, -750.f)];

// set the floor height, this will be the minimum y-Position for all entities
[[GameMechanics sharedGameMechanics] setFloorHeight:20.f];
 }

 #pragma mark - Update & Input Events

 -(void) accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer
    didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
 {
// controls how quickly velocity decelerates (lower = quicker to change direction)
float deceleration = 0.2f;
// determines how sensitive the accelerometer reacts (higher = more sensitive)
float sensitivity = 300.0f;
// how fast the velocity can be at most
float maxVelocity = 500;

// adjust velocity based on current accelerometer acceleration
float velocityX = knight.velocity.x * deceleration + acceleration.y * sensitivity;

// we must limit the maximum velocity of the player sprite, in both directions
if (knight.velocity.x > maxVelocity)
{
    velocityX = maxVelocity;
}
else if (knight.velocity.x < - maxVelocity)
{
    velocityX = - maxVelocity;
}

knight.velocity = ccp(velocityX, knight.velocity.y);
 }
```

My attempt in converting self.acceleratorEnabled:

```
 #pragma mark - Scene Lifecycle

 - (void)onEnterTransitionDidFinish
 {
// setup a gesture listener for jumping and stabbing gestures
[KKInput sharedInput].gestureSwipeEnabled = TRUE;
// register for accelerometer input, to controll the knight
//self.acceleratorEnabled = YES;

[super onEnter];
_label.position = ccp(self.contentSize.width/2, self.contentSize.height/2);
[_motionManager startAccelerometerUpdates];

if (self.showMainMenu)
{
    // add main menu
    MainMenuLayer *mainMenuLayer = [[MainMenuLayer alloc] init];
    [self addChild:mainMenuLayer z:MAX_INT];
} else
{
    // start game directly
    [self showHUD:TRUE];
    [self startGame];
}
 }

 - (void)onExit
 {
// very important! deactivate the gestureInput, otherwise touches on scrollviews and tableviews will be cancelled!
[KKInput sharedInput].gestureSwipeEnabled = FALSE;
//self.acceleratorEnabled = FALSE;
[super onExit];
[_motionManager stopAccelerometerUpdates];
 }
```

Comment: So where is `accelerometerEnabled` declared?

Comment: Has been removed, use regular motion events via CMMotionManager: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/motion_event_basics/motion_event_basics.html

Comment: @HotLicks - Good question.  How do I declare it?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D - How do I use regular motion events?  I want to be able to tap the screen to make the in-game character jump or do some kind of movement while running in a specific direction.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D How would I be able to convert the `self.accelerometerEnabled` into the new CMMotionManager code?

Comment: If you don't know how to declare a property, you need to step away from the keyboard and find a book on Objective-C programming.

Comment: @HotLicks - I've tried.  It's like reading a math book while doing actual math problems in a book (back in school).  85% of the time, the tutorial and my brain do not get along to actually solve the problems that I need to solve.  Every game I see has code BASED on the code taught in an objective-c book, though I have no idea how to actually correlate and associate the code that is being taught and the code that is actually being executed in the game.  It's like I am better off studying code that is actually being executed in the games and analysing how they function.

Comment: If you can find me a newbie dummy programming book that actually teaches code based on existing games, I'd be excited to read it ;)  Most games will execute code in different ways, but a book will show only one way to execute a code, making it VERY confusing.

Comment: The point is, all you're ever going to learn to do is to write games. On one specific platform.  And you'll never be able to do anything truly new.  You need to learn the *principles* involved.  Forget, for a few months, about the problems you "need to solve" and think about what you need to learn.

Comment: And, in particular, if you don't know what a property is or how to declare one you're Objective-C programming career is doomed.

Comment: For me personally, I like to go directly into the juicy stuff.  I'll learn the principles along the way.  It's how I learn.  I like learning about stuff as they apply to stuff.  I learn the principles subconsciously.  I don't want to read a definition on what a property is....it bores me.  I would rather see a real source code and have a textbook say "this is a property.  This is how it applies to the game. bla bla bla"

Comment: But what will you do when folks on SO get tired of answering questions like "Why can't I reference something I never declared"?

Comment: Why do you assume folks will get tired?  I thought folks get points for answering questions?  It's not like I intentionally ask stupid questions.

Comment: @HotLicks - Is that supposed to be an insult?  If so, it amuses me.  I have the utmost respect for cashiers in fast food restaurants; however I have a management job that serves me well and allows me to serve other people.  Anyways, you never gave any resolution to my question.  If you're going to tell someone how they should approach programming, at least have the common courtesy to give them some knowledge or clue as to how they should solve their problem with some code.

Comment: I gave you a clue:  *Read a proper book on the subject.*  (And what is it you think I can do with 23,000 points??  That and $3 will get me a cup of coffee at Starbucks.)

Comment: Personal accomplishment...the sense that you helped a newbie programmer.  I've edited my .h file so that acceleratorEnabled has been declared.  Now I have one more error that I'm trying to figure out.  By the way, you never mentioned to me what book I should read.

Comment: "The C Programming Language", by Kernighan and Ritchie.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 7 you need to use the `CMMotionManager`.
I have written a tutorial about how to use the accelerometer with iOS7 and Cocos2D 3.0:
https://www.makegameswith.us/gamernews/371/accelerometer-with-cocos2d-30-and-ios-7

Comment: Great tutorial.  Though I have a few questions though.  I'll update my question in the post.  By the way, your header import code is wrong....should be: #import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>.  Looked it up on the Apple developer site.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing this out. It was an issue with our syntax highlighting and has been fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

In .h

```
#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>

@interface Scene : CCScene 
{
    CMMotionManager* motionManager;

}
```

In .m

```
//put in init
motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init]; //init motion manager
[motionManager startAccelerometerUpdates]; //start accelerometer
[self scheduleUpdate]; //call

-(void)update:(CCTime)delta
{
    CMAccelerometerData* accelerometerData = motionManager.accelerometerData;
    CMAcceleration acceleration = accelerometerData.acceleration;

    // controls how quickly velocity decelerates (lower = quicker to change direction)
    float deceleration = 0.2f;
    // determines how sensitive the accelerometer reacts (higher = more sensitive)
    float sensitivity = 300.0f;
    // how fast the velocity can be at most
    float maxVelocity = 500;

// adjust velocity based on current accelerometer acceleration
float velocityX = knight.velocity.x * deceleration + acceleration.y * sensitivity;

// we must limit the maximum velocity of the player sprite, in both directions
if (knight.velocity.x > maxVelocity)
{
    velocityX = maxVelocity;
}
else if (knight.velocity.x < - maxVelocity)
{
    velocityX = - maxVelocity;
}

knight.velocity = ccp(velocityX, knight.velocity.y);


}
```

Comment: how would I combine the code you have in .m with the code I have in my GameLayer.m?  I have two instances of `void` where the accelerator property is being declared.

Comment: I updated update funcion. No need for -(void) accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *). Hope this helps.

Comment: `motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init]; //init motion manager` Type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'.   Initializer element is not a compile-time constant.
`[motionManager startAccelerometerUpdates]; //start accelerometer` Missing '[' at start of message send expression.
`[self scheduleUpdate]; //call` Use of undeclared identifier 'self'
`-(void)update:(CCTime)delta` Expected a type
`CMAccelerometerData* accelerometerData = motionManager.` Use of undeclared identifier 'motionManager'; did you mean '_motionManager'?

Comment: I'm using this exact code in my cocos v3 arc project and it's working fine. motionManager is declared in .h and you could rename it to _motionManager if you want to.

Comment: Changed the code a bit...moved stuff around.  Got one error popping up.  The code in .m file: `- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    
    if (self)
    {
        //put in init
        _motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init]; //init motion manager
        [CMMotionManager startAccelerometerUpdates]; //start accelerometer
        [self scheduleUpdate]; //call`  The error is on `startAccelerometerUpdates` saying No known class method for selector 'startAccelerometerUpdates'

Comment: my .h file says: `#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>

@interface Scene : CCScene
{
    CMMotionManager* _motionManager;
    
}
@end

@interface GameplayLayer : CCLayer <StoreDisplayNeedsUpdate, UIAccelerometerDelegate,PauseScreenDelegate>
{
    BOOL _accelerometerEnabled;
    HealthDisplayNode *healthDisplayNode;
    ScoreboardEntryNode *coinsDisplayNode;`